# "body" overflow hidden or scroll via onclick function

Tags: javascript, scroll, onclick, overflow

I have a dropdown menu which covers the whole page if opened (100vh + 100 vw) and I try to disable the scrolling of the body when I click the dropdown menu button.

Adding and removing a class on click didn't worked for me for some reason but adding directly a style worked for me perfectly via: `<a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';>`

But by clicking the link again doesn't set the overflow to scroll again, so is anyone able to help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems, you are not removing the styling after its already 'hidden', and you missed a quotation mark at the end of onclick. The bellow code will check if the body overflow is hidden or not before changing between them.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.body.style.overflow = document.body.style.overflow == 'hidden' ? 'auto' : 'hidden' "/>
```

i would also suggest using a `button` insted of a `a` element when used to run javascript.

```
<button onclick="document.body.style.overflow = document.body.style.overflow == 'hidden' ? 'auto' : 'hidden' "/>
```

If you are looking for toggling a class, this should work. Where `mystyle` is the classname of the class you are toggling.

```
<button onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('mystyle')"/>
```

If toggling a class does not work, you have a specificity problem where other css styling applies over the "toggled class", you can check this via the element tab in developer tools.

Comment: Very Cool, thanks a ton that actually did the trick. May i also ask if there is way to have a control mechanism which checks the overflow state of the body because i have actually five dropdown menu buttons in the header and it can easily turn into a memory game if someone misclicks accidentally a neighbouring button.

Comment: The answer to that is heavily dependent on how the dropdown menus works? is it controlled and based on JavaScript? or is it pure html and css?

Comment: I use Bootstrap (for the first time), i would normally use addClass here but the script i use has already two seperate body elements for night & day mode (with tons of if/else conditions) and i am not yet advanced enough with my coding skills to alter the related files like a rookie, that's why i'm looking for a pragmatic approach... So i use a script based on Bootstrap.